# Blue and white rectangle

Tags: macos, screen

I just restarted my MacBook Pro and I am now getting a blue and white rectangle near the top right corner of my screen. Does anyone know what this is or what is causing it?

MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch, Late 2013, Version 10.11.3.

[image]

After restarting my laptop again, the box was not there immediately, but showed up before everything was fully loaded in a slightly different location.

I am unable to click on the box, and trying to drag it just creates the regular selection box as if nothing is there.

**Update**: I ran Apple's diagnostics and it claimed there is nothing wrong with the machine itself.

**Update 2**: I attempted to restart my machine into safe mode a couple times but it did not seem to work. It looked like a normal load sequence, just hanging before asking for my login credentials. However, after a regular login, I no longer seem to have this issue. Hopefully it stays this way.

Comment: Please add your system version. Additionally restart your Mac pressing the Shift key (= Safe Mode) and report the result.

Comment: You can use "Accessibility Inspector" from Xcode and try to track the App responsible of showing this window (maybe from AXApplication accessibilityLabel).

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Accessibility Inspector shows no additional or different information from the desktop itself.

Comment: Looks like better touch tool to me?

Comment: This rectangle looks like it's from [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12).

Comment: I have neither BetterSnapTool nor BetterTouchTool.

Comment: As stated in an update, I'm not currently having this issue. I also had a call with apple support and they had me reset the NVRAM. I'm really not sure what I should do with this question.

Comment: @JustinWood Booting to Safe Mode wasn't intended to solve your problem. It just stops any non-Apple kernel extension and some start-up items. Ruling out an OS X operating system problem facilitates the search for the real culprit

Comment: @klanomath I know. I was unable to actually get into safe mode though, so I can't give any information as to whether this was still occurring in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of steps to possibly resolve your problem:

1. Reset Finder: This is a basic step, just open up `Force Quit Applications` by calling `⌘-⌥-esc` and then press finder and reset it.
2. Open `Terminal` and enter the command `killall Finder`. If it goes away then it's a problem with finder.
3. Open Activity Monitor: If there is anything irregular open in activity monitor just close it. **However**, be *very* careful with Activity Monitor. It's easy to close something that will crash your machine.

Comment: You're welcome to post suggestions as answers in most cases. I've edited your answer to remove the "maybe this should be a comment" statement.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't 100% sure on the rules as I'm new to Ask Different.